# Gardening with negative or positive ORP (oxidation reduction potential) water

Tags: watering, germination, fruits, hydroponic, aeroponics

Gardening with negative or positive ORP (oxidation reduction potential) water.

I know ORP is related to Ph but has anyone done any experiments with negative ORP vs Positive ORP growth? From soaking seeds to fruiting plants?  The ranges I'm looking at are from -1000mV to +1000mV.  Even if they find a certain ORP kills a plant it would be good to know since it would be another possible way to get rid of "weeds".

Comment: Why are you worried about this? It's small potatoes in horticulture.

Comment: I'm not worried just very intrigued.
https://anrcatalog.ucanr.edu/pdf/8149.pdf

Comment: @Jurp I see what you did there.